# Zend-Framework2, Form Layout is Broken

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am learning Zend by following `Getting Started with Zend Framework 2` tutorial but I am facing a prolem with the form layout, it's broken:
[image]

How do I fix this issue to make it likes the form in the tutorial:
[image]

AlbumForm code:

```
 public function __construct($name = null)
 {
     // we want to ignore the name passed
     parent::__construct('album');

     $this->add(array(
         'name' => 'id',
         'type' => 'Hidden',
     ));
     $this->add(array(
         'name' => 'title',
         'type' => 'Text',
         'options' => array(
             'label' => 'Title',
         ),
     ));
     $this->add(array(
         'name' => 'artist',
         'type' => 'Text',
         'options' => array(
             'label' => 'Artist',
         ),
     ));
     $this->add(array(
         'name' => 'submit',
         'type' => 'Submit',
         'attributes' => array(
             'value' => 'Go',
             'id' => 'submitbutton',
         ),
     ));
 }
```

and the view code:

```
<?php
// module/Album/view/album/album/add.phtml:

$title = 'Add new album';
$this->headTitle($title);
?>
<h1><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h1>
<?php
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('album', array('action' => 'add')));
$form->prepare();

echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
echo $this->formHidden($form->get('id'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('title'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('artist'));
echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit'));
echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```

Answer (score 0):

Zend Framework has possibility to change style in elements. to add "clear:both;" style I think will solve problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="form_element">
    <?php
        $artist = $form->get('artist');
        echo $this->formRow($artist);
    ?></div>
    <div style="clear:left;"></div>

    <div class="form_element">
    <?php
        $title = $form->get('title');
        echo $this->formRow($title);
    ?></div>
```

Comment: sorry but it doesn't work again. I have edited the question to add my code. Please, help to review.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>';
echo $this->formRow($form->get('title'));
echo '<div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>';
echo $this->formRow($form->get('artist'));
echo '<div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>';
echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit'));
echo '<div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>';
```

Comment: In the tutorial, the label and the box are in 2 seperate rows. Doing as your code just break 'title' and 'artist' but could not break the label and the box.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and fastest way is to add this css..

```
form label
{
  display: block;
}
```

Note that it will be slightly different from the tutorial.